# Am I sharing Layers ? - keras network modeling

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a shared network models to make a model that has multiple inputs. my code is :

```
f1 = 128
f2 = 256
f3 = 1
shared_conv1 = L.Conv2D(filters=f1, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=1, padding='same',name='shared_conv1')
shared_conv2 = L.Conv2D(filters=f1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same',name='shared_conv2')
shared_conv3 = L.Conv2D(filters=f1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=1, padding='same',name='shared_conv3')

shared_batch1 =  L.BatchNormalization(name='shared_batch1')
shared_batch2 =  L.BatchNormalization(name='shared_batch2')
shared_batch3 =  L.BatchNormalization(name='shared_batch3')

shared_relu1 = L.ReLU(name='shared_relu1')
shared_relu2 = L.ReLU(name='shared_relu2')
shared_relu3 = L.ReLU(name='shared_relu3')

for i in range(length):
     x_64 = shared_conv1(input[i])
     x_64 = shared_batch1(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_relu1(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_conv2(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_batch2(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_relu2(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_conv3(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_batch3(x_64)
     x_64 = shared_relu3(x_64)
     print(x_64)
```

I want to use 8 input, and want x_64 to be output 8 times, and I saw print result like this :

```
Tensor("shared_relu1_3/Relu:0", shape=(None, 64, 64, 128), dtype=float32)
Tensor("shared_relu1_3_1/Relu:0", shape=(None, 64, 64, 128), dtype=float32)
Tensor("shared_relu1_3_2/Relu:0", shape=(None, 64, 64, 128), dtype=float32)
```

Since I expected "shared_relu1_3/Relu:0" to be printed 3 times, I could not judge that my network is worked as shared network correctly. 
Am I doint right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is working correctly, what it might confuse you is that the output tensors actually represent computation, so each of them are different but it does not mean that the weights are different, they are being shared.

Sharing works by passing several tensors through the same layer instance, since layers are the ones that have the weights inside them. So it should be working as expected.

Also there is no need to share ReLU's, since they do not have weights. Only layers that have weights should be shared if needed.